# Energy of flyback with multiple outputs

Tags: power, switch-mode-power-supply, flyback, energy

Where does the additional energy for flyback with multiple outputs come from?

It appears that I can add as many secondary outputs as I want, but the primary voltage is Vin, and the primary current can be deduced from V=Ldi/dt => i(t) = Vin*t/L (when switch is on), therefore power in primary is constant (V*I), therefore I am not sure where the power for the additional secondary windings come from if the power in the primary stays the same. Thought that maybe it has to do something with voltage\current mirroring to the primary.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *where does the additional energy for flyback with multiple
> outputs come from?*

The primary voltage is "held across" the primary inductance for as long as it takes to acquire sufficient energy to match the energy requirement of the secondary load(s). This is where the control of duty cycle comes in. A higher power requirement in the load(s) means that the energy transferred in each switching cycle must increase and that means increasing duty cycle in DCM or raising the average primary current in CCM.

$$\text{Total load power  = energy transferred each cycle}\times \text{switching frequency}$$

In DCM (see picture below) you only get more energy per cycle by increasing the duty cycle.

Primary and secondary current waveforms in DCM. Transformer ratio is 1:1: -

[image]

Equivalent circuit: -

[image]

As load power increases, the duty cycle increases giving more time for the primary to "charge" with energy. The "hold" time will shorten as the secondary power requirement grows. But remember, the basic flyback circuit cannot do this on its own; it needs a controller that monitors one of the output voltages (the "chosen one") and adjusts duty cycle to keep that voltage regulated.

The other windings on the secondary side are a little bit outside the control loop and may grow their voltages a few percent as the controller increases the duty cycle to maintain the "chosen" secondary voltage regulated.

Pictures from [here](http://www.stades.co.uk/Flyback/flyback%20DCM2.html) and [here](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276436#answer-276438).

> *therefore power in primary is constant*

No, it's dependent on duty cycle i.e. how long you apply Vin to the primary winding for.

---

Edited to add CCM waveforms: -

[image]

In CCM, if the load current becomes too high, the output voltage will tend to droop (and di/dt will flatten). The knock-on effect of this is that there will be more magnetic field in the core when the charging period restarts and, at the end of the charging period, the peak primary current will naturally be a little higher. Thus, duty cycle remains the same but, the average primary current has increased to deliver the increased secondary energy.

Comment: But flyback transfer function is Vo/Vi = n*D/(1-D) (where D is the duty cycle, and n is the windings ratio), so if we keep Vo and Vi constant, we can derive the duty cycle. But you say that different loads change the Duty cycle, but the whole point is keeping constant Vo, Vi (and therefore constant Duty cycle), so how is it logical?

Comment: @Jonathan Higher output current from the transformer (note: not the PSU output current) affects the slope of the green line. If you draw more current in total, the line goes to 0 faster.

Comment: @Jonathan that formula applies when the device is operated in CCM mode. On light loads, the flyback is highly likely to be in DCM mode. In CCM mode the load changes are dealt with by the overall current waveforms rising or falling and so power does increase to suit the load(s).

Comment: @user253751 that's not really true except when dealing with load changes i.e. transients. Once the load has stabilized, the slope of the green line is related to the output voltage and the equivalent secondary inductance.

Comment: @Andyaka don't you draw the same current from the transformer no matter what the load is (but for more or less time, according to the chart)? But when you add more taps, you draw more current?

Comment: @user253751 if the length of time that the green line is falling cannot sustain all the load currents then the output voltage must drop and then, the duty cycle needs to increase to allow a higher energy transfer per switching cycle. It's not *the same current* - it slopes downwards until it hits zero (DCM) or the switching cycle begins again (CCM).

Comment: "And, you only get more energy per cycle by increasing the duty cycle." This is true when the SMPS is in discontinuous conduction mode, but is not true in continuous conduction mode. See [my answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/545057/268467) to a related question.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy that's not true. I have thought about this. In CCM, if the load current is too high (a sudden transient) then we increase duty cycle (a little) and, in effect, we create a situation where the average current rises and things then stabilize back to the same duty cycle but with a higher average current to match energy per cycle to the power requirements of the load. For a buck converter, an increased load current naturally causes the average current in CCM to rise; it's a little less clear in a flyback converter because energy transfer is disconnected from energy charge.

Comment: Yes, if there is a sudden change in load, there will be a transient change in voltage. But it is not true that for a fixed frequency and duty cycle, there is a fixed output current or power, and the only way to increase it is to increase duty cycle. Not only does that contradict the well known formulae for the relationships between voltage and duty cycle, but we can empirically verify that for the same duty cycle we can have different output currents and output powers. Anyone can simulate the circuit provided in the answer linked to above.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy it's a buck converter so it's not really relevant here though. Maybe you might be right for a flyback in CCM?

Comment: @Andyaka The same principles apply. In DCM, the energy transfered in one cycle depends upon duty. But in CCM, the energy transfered in one cycle depends not only on duty, but on the residual current through the inductor from the previous cycles.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy OK, you've convinced me - I shall make an amendment.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the flyback principle is to inject to C1 and C2 charge boosts often enough to keep the voltages at he wanted values. The charging pulses are also designed to be small enough to prevent too high voltage jumps.

You at first charge some magnetic energy to the core of the transformer by letting S conduct a while. The primary current grows with rate Vin/primary inductance. It's amperes/second if Vin is in volts ant the inductance is in henries.

Then you let the magnetic field collapse by opening S. Magnetic field has the property it never collapses instantly. It generates just as much electric field as needed to cause enough voltage to the windings to let the current flow in at least one of the windings so that the current decays gradually, not instantly. The induced pulse hopefully goes through the diodes to charge C1 and C2 and S is strong enough to hold the induced voltage with no smoke.

The idea is to generate induced pulses often enough to keep C1 and C2 in the wanted voltages. The control circuit takes care of this aspect. If there's not enough new current pulses to C1 and C2 the voltages drop.

If it happens that you feel you do not know well enough how the inductors work check this old case: [https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/282053/how-does-the-inductor-really-induce-voltage?r=SearchResults&s=1|63.9320](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/282053/how-does-the-inductor-really-induce-voltage?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C63.9320)