# How do I get half of my supply voltage without a resistive voltage divider?

Tags: voltage

On my 3D-printer the fans run on 24 V and I have a 12 V fan that I would like to use. Both fans are voltage controlled.

What I need is a circuit to always get half the voltage, so if the supply is 24V then the output should be 12V. If the supply is 23V then the output should be 11.5V, and so on.

I don't know what to do. Can you guys help me?

[Fan datasheet.](https://noctua.at/en/products/fan/nf-a4x20-flx/specification)

Comment: Fan data sheet links are probably needed.

Comment: Welcome! A 24 ->12 V DC-DC converter?

Comment: You can waste half the voltage using a *voltage regulator*, or you can, for a presumably higher investment, waste a couple of percent using a *DC-DC converter*.

Comment: @winny will I be Able to control the fan speed when using a DC-DC converter. I would like the fan to not spin at full speed (12v) all the time.

Comment: Can you use 2x 12V fans in series?

Comment: Depends on how it's controlled. Are you entirely sure it's proportional voltage control out from the 3D printer. It exists but is usually the last option for any manufacturer.

Comment: Why are you against using a resistor divider? The easiest way to always get half the input voltage would be a resistor divider and an op-amp buffer with the proper current output to drive your fans.

Comment: @md-raz thank you I will try this.

Comment: Why do you need proportional voltage? It's unlikely that the 3D printer uses voltage control to change the fan speed. PWM is more likely.

Comment: @Drew I tried hooking the fan output up to my scope and there was no pwm, just varying voltage.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a resistive divider somewhere in your circuit, that's pretty much the easiest way to divide a voltage, but the divider doesn't have to be used to drive the load directly.

What you would do is use the divider to sense the input voltage and give you a reference point of half that voltage, that reference is then used by a regulator of some sort to drive the load. This can be a linear regulator, or some type of switching regulator. The output of the regulator is sensed and compared to the reference in an error amplifier, the output of the error amplifier adjusts the regulator to keep those voltages the same. This is the same as any regulator works, except that usually you use a fixed reference voltage but in this case you're taking the reference as half the supply voltage.

Answer (score 0):

First, fix your supply voltage range. A switching voltage regulator like this should work: [VX78012-500](https://www.digikey.nl/en/products/detail/cui-inc/VX78012-500/7350285?s=N4IgTCBcDaIGoA0DsAOADARjAWgKxrRAF0BfIA)

For this regulator, the input can vary from 15 V to 36 V (for a +12 V output) but the output will be maintained at +12 V.

Also, your fan has a max input current rating of 500 mA which is the maximum current providing capability of this regulator.

Comment: I might not have been clear enough in my post, but I don't want the output voltage to be stable/fixed/constant. It should vary with the supply voltage.

Comment: @LassePedersen Is the fan datasheet relevant then?

Comment: I don't think so but someone asked for them in a comment.

Comment: He can search on Aliexpress for "LM2596S", they have cheap modules with this chip. Example: https://de.aliexpress.com/item/32813155284.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use a linear regulator and tie the feedback to the input.

You have to make sure that:

- Your 24V lies within the input voltage range.
- The feedback pin can handle the exposed voltage over the full input range.
- The power due to voltage drop (0.05A of FAN and 12V drop) will not exceed the specs of the linear regulator.

It could look like this with an LT3088:

[image: LT3088 LTSpice Schematic]

You should keep in mind that if the fancontroller does use the RPM speed signal of your FAN that you maybe have to protect the RPM input of the controller. This could be done with a Schottky diode and pullup resistor (lets call it "open-collector hack.") Maybe this is already implemented in your circuit.

[image: OC-Hack Schottky LTSpice Schematic]

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a Stepdown voltage regulator module, you can get one if you search on Aliexpress or eBay.

- LM2596 with 7 segment voltage meter (easy to adjust without multimeter):
  3€ -> https://de.aliexpress.com/item/1005004850634227.html
- LM2596S with only a poti to adjust the voltage, you need a multimeter:
  2€ -> https://de.aliexpress.com/item/10000000656280.html

If the 3D-printer board is using the signal pin (for the number of revolutions) from the fan (to know that the fan is running or not), than you have to separate the cable and connect this signal-pin directly to the board.

Answer (score 0):

Nitpicky on diction, you need neither *regulator* (something with (negative) feedback) nor *resistive* voltage divider.
Short of looking at step-down charge pumps,
a buck converter with a fixed 50% duty cycle should do nicely:
do you have a clock signal in the range of 44 to some hundred kHz on hand?

Comment: According to this thread: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/544956/how-does-a-buck-converter-maintain-a-constant-voltage  there would be transients and the voltage would vary depending on the load, if using a constant duty cycle.

Comment: Would a fan motor present a load varying significantly? Would a fan, EC or not, care?